# Is there a function discontinuous on $C = \{\frac{m}{2^{n-1}} \in \Bbb R ; m \in \Bbb Z, n \in \Bbb N \} $?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given the set $C = \{\frac{m}{2^{k-1}} \in \Bbb R ; m \in \Bbb Z,k \in \Bbb N \} $, is there a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that the set of discontinuous points of f are equal to C? 
Information that maybe be useful: C is dense on $\Bbb R$.

I think there might be something in the way of $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \notin C$} \\
\frac{1}{k}, & \text{if $x = \frac{m}{2^{k-1}} \in C$}
\end{cases}$

In this case:

- If $a \in C$, there is a sequence $(x_n) \subset \Bbb R \setminus C$ such that $\lim(x_n)=a$. Then $\lim f(x_n)=0\neq f(a)$. Therefore, f is discontinuous at $a \in C$.
- If $a \in \Bbb R \setminus C$, we must show that: $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 (\exists \delta \gt 0(|x-a| \lt \delta \to |f(x)-f(a)| \lt \epsilon))$. For $x \in \Bbb R \setminus C$ it's trivial, because in this case $|f(x)-f(a)|=0 \lt \epsilon$. But now I'm having trouble to show for $x \in C$. As I see it, intuitively, if $x = \frac{m}{2^{k-1}}$ is very close to $a \notin C$, then k must be very large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You correctly demonstrated that $f$ is discontinuous at every $a \in C$.

Now let $a \in \Bbb R \setminus C$ and $\epsilon > 0$. The interval $[a-1, a+1]$ contains only finitely many fractions $\frac{m}{2^{k-1}}$ with $m \in \Bbb Z$, $k \in \Bbb N$, and $k \le 1/\epsilon$. Therefore we can define
$$
 \delta = \min \{ | a - \frac{m}{2^{k-1}}| : m \in \Bbb Z, k \in \Bbb N, k \le \frac{1}{\epsilon}\} > 0 \, .
$$
If $|x - a| < \delta$ then either $x \in \Bbb R \setminus C$ or $x = \frac{m}{2^{k-1}}$ with $k > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. In the first case is $|f(x) - f(a)| = 0$, and in the second case is $|f(x) - f(a)| = \frac 1k < \epsilon$.

This shows that $f$ is continuous at every $a \in \Bbb R \setminus C$.

Comment: In both case, we have $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=0$.

Comment: @Riemann: You are right. If we consider the set $[a-1, a+1] \setminus \{ a \}$ then the argument works for all $a \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, just like the proof of Riemann function!